# Google Maps v3 Terrain View By Default

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make my google maps embed default to terrain view. Attached is my code that loads everything correctly except the map options where I set the default view to terrain. I have it set up to only limit the choices to only terrain but when you initially load the page it is on the default hybrid view.

```
var map, marker, latLngToPixel;
var middle_earth_MORADOR = new google.maps.LatLng(38, 0);

function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: middle_earth_MORADOR,
        backgroundColor: "#000",
         mapTypeControlOptions: {
             mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]
         },
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var locations = [
        // PHP LOOP FOR FEATURED PROJECTS   
    ];

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);

    var styledMapOptions = {
        map: map,
        name: "map"
    }

    var build =  new google.maps.StyledMapType(styledMapOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set('map', build);
    map.setMapTypeId('map');
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {    

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            icon: 'http://staging.******.com/css/images/pin.png',
            map: map,
        });

         marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
         setTimeout(function(){ marker.setAnimation(null); }, 1750);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                window.location = "http://staging.******.com/projects/" + locations[i][4];
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can disable the default UI of map by setting the property `disableDefaultUI` to true, and then set in the options the `TERRAIN` as the `mapTypeId` as how I did it below:

```
function loadMap() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lan);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: myLatlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
//code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('Map'), {  

  mapTypeId: 'terrain'

});
```